# How to upgrade php from using a tar.gz file in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

all, I have a problem related to php upgrade. I currently use 5.3.x, and would like to upgrade to latest 5.4.26, using "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5" can only upgrade to version [5.4.25](http://php.net/releases/), but the latest version now should be [5.4.26](http://www.php.net/). I tried to upgrade it using a tar.gz file. But after an installation, I have problem to use the curl module. And re-install curl, seems it can not be connected to the current installed php version. May I know how can I do this tar.gz upgrade correctly, with all the other installed modules correctly be connected?

It seems it is impossible to upgrade php installed using "apt-get install" by tat.gz installation. The php.ini and other extensions files are totally messed up, and easy to have two versions of php installed. So, if a tar.gz installation is needed, then the installed php must be uninstalled first. Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: Is there something specific to [this release](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.26) you absolutely need? If not, stick to the latest apt upgrade; .26 will propagate soon enough...

Comment: @Digital Chris, not really, just want to keep consistent with other developer(but they use Windows, easy to install new version). Though I can wait till 5.4.26 is available using "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5". But I also hope to know whether is it possible to use tar.gz to manually install it.

Comment: You can `wget {url of tar.gz}` and install it, but it might cause issues later when you want to go back to using `apt`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is actually php 5.5.3.

If I were you, I would just wait until April 17th, and upgrade to 14.04. That upgrade will include the latest version of PHP.

Otherwise, your best bet would be to run `do-release-upgrade` a few times and get yourself up to 13.10

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But we will use 12.04 for sometime, and do not have plan to upgrade to 14.04. It is true that PHP already have 5.5.x, but 5.4.x is still keeping updated. And 5.4.26 is the latest for 5.4.